# Ruby on Rails - Passing data directly to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update or populate a table on click by passing variables.

For checkbox, I have done following, which works perfectly.

```
<td><%= check_box_tag item_counter, item.to_json, false,
                          {:class => 'show', :onclick => "select.update(this)"}%></td>
```

and the jquery function is,

```
 $(function () {
     select.init();
  });

select = {
   update: function (obj) {
   //TABLE UPDATE LOGIC MISSING FOR SIMPLICITY
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

Now I need to creat a link for similar functionality like check_box_tag, I have done something like this,

```
<%= link_to item_count[:name],"#", {:onclick => "select.update(this)", :id => item_count_counter} %>
```

How do I pass the parameters to my jquery function in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen using rails tag helpers work for things similar to what you are describing.  However, it can get a little messy when you want to incorporate client side functionality into it.

It might be worth ditching the `<%= %>` simply for clarity - for yourself at least.

But provided you're committed to the tag helper, do you have any error messages from the js console you can show?  In the first example - the helper is nested in a `<td>`, is that still the case in the second example?  Sometimes using `id:` can cause issues with other variables in scope in js.